# CSS - Absolute positioned element appear at different places in different screen resolutions

Tags: html, css

I have a streamed flash radio on my website and i set it to it's current position with absolute position. The problem is that with different resolutions it appears at different places. How do i fix this?

Thx!

Comment: make the parent div position:relative;

Comment: There is no parent div - It's in a <header> tag.

Comment: the body width is set to 1024px

Comment: can u post your css code here.

Comment: oh, it wasn't the body with, its a div for the full page: #teljes
{
 width: 1024px;
 height: 768px;
 margin: 0px auto;
} and for the radio:object{
    position:absolute;
    left:953px;
    top:55px;
}

Comment: add position relative to that div #teljes

Answer (score 1):

An absolute position element is positioned relative to the first parent element that has a position other than static. Make sure the element your are absolutely positioning is not contained in an element which shifts position.

Answer (score 0):

**Add `position:relative` your `#teljes` :**

```
#teljes { width: 1024px; height: 768px; margin: 0px auto; position:relative;}
```

Adding `position:relative;` to div will make all the absolute positioned children to take position according to parent div.

Comment: Please add an explaination why this is the solution. This Answer will then suit a broader range of knowledge seekers.